# How can i fill data to PDF file on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pdf, generate

I am using Laravel and I have pdf file and i need dinamicaly fill there some fields data.
How can i do this without PDF View?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can't edit a pdf file to fill his fields, what you can do is generate a pdf file and pass the content with the fields already filled, here is a library to do it: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. I can do it by [php-pdftk library](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk) library.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot edit the pdf files directly , you got to create fields inside the pdf which can be read by the library. You can try this package [strongbond/pdf-filler-laravel](https://packagist.org/packages/strongbond/pdf-filler-laravel) , i had a similar situation also wanted to add signature into the pdf which lead me to build this library.